# What type of port has a logo with one long line and three short lines under?

Tags: port

On the side of my laptop (ThinkPad x40) there is an odd place for connecting wires, directly under one of the USB ports. The port looks similar to those for USB, with a similar rectangular shape and height, but is not as wide. The identifying logo to the left of the port looks a bit like a trigram, with one long line at the top, and a broken line with three segments at the bottom:

```
**********************
******  ******  ******
```

I checked the repair manual for the laptop. All other ports have labels, but not this one. What is it for?

Comment: There are also the Dell D620 chargers https://i.stack.imgur.com/euZ6L.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a USB Power Connector - some older external CD drives used an odd 'stacked' connector that had power as well

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PitiE6R.png]

Lenovo has *excellent* documentation on these models (inherited from IBM) and [you can find it here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/migr-53710)

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a symbol for a specific connector, it is the symbol for Direct Current.
So while it's used on a laptop to indicate where the power cord get connected, it's not a particular type of USB or serial connector.

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Direct_current_symbol.svg

Answer (score 2):

[image: Getac V100]

> Above is the left side of the V100, with ports closed and opened. You can see the port covers with their ears on top and the large white icons that indicate what port or connector is beneath. From left to right are the power connector (covered), two USB 2.0 ports, modem and gigabit LAN jacks, and the card slot compartment that can accommodate two PC Type II cards or one Type III card (changed to one PC Card and one ExpressCard slot in June of 2009). Below that is a SD Card slot. Customers can sacrifice one Type II slot and get a Smart Card reader instead.

According to this, the logo would be for your power supply port.  I can confirm that the same symbol exists next to the power port on my 10" Asus laptop as well.  Can't say I've ever seen a rectangular one though, and usually people know where they plug their power cord into.

Source: http://ruggedpcreview.com/3_notebooks_getac_v100_ORIG.html

Comment: The logo shown is the same, but my power supply plugs into another port, marked with three circles: `o-o-o`. Is this some kind of additional power place? Why would the laptop have two?

Comment: I really couldn't say why, unless perhaps one port is for power going through the battery, and one perhaps bypassing the battery altogether?